Definiton of the "pass" in backpass
Played in a game a couple of nights ago and the following backpass scenario happened:

Ball was coming at speed into the area so the defender stepped on the ball to slow it down and stop it to make it easier for the goalkeeper to control. Can the keeper now handle it or will that be considered an illegal backpass?

This sparked a couple more questions:

Defender A passes to Defender B who doesn't touch it but leaves/dummies it for the keeper. Can the keeper pick it up now?

Can a keeper rush off his line and catch his own defender unawares, tackle him, take the ball off him and pick it up?


I believe that all these scenarios ask what is the definition of "pass" in backpass. Is it an intentional passing of the ball from the defender to the keeper i.e. the ball must travel in the direction from the defender to the keeper powered by an intentional touch from the defender? This will therefore mean that all the cases above will be considered legal. Or is it defined as an "intentional touch", which will rule 1 illegal, 3 legal and 2 somewhere in between. Or something else?

As per Law 12, Section 2 of the Rules of the Game, an indirect free kick is only awarded if the ball "has been deliberately kicked to the goalkeeper by a team-mate" before they pick it up. As per this wording:

As per the comments, the goalkeeper cannot handle the ball in this case, as the slowing down of the ball with the foot constitutes a "kick".
The goalkeeper can handle the ball in this place, as it had been kicked to Defender B, not them.
Again, the goalkeeper can handle the ball in this instance, as they won it themselves rather than having it passed to them. (Practically speaking, this would never happen in a professional game.)

Note as well that the rule only disallows deliberate kicks - it is legal for a defender to, for example, head the ball back towards their goalkeeper.

In my opinion stopping the ball with the foot with intent to let the goalkeeper pick it up can be explained as passing. If it were an obvious move I'd probably whistle for an indirect. However this is gray territory, I'll ask a few other refs!

@PaulPalmpje you're correct. It's a deliberate play so the keeper is not allowed to pick up the ball. If this situation happened by accident, this would have been a legal move.

@dly I asked a few other refs and they agree. It's a deliberate play with the foot and thus the goalkeeper is not allowed to pick up the ball with his hands.

@PaulPalmpje Thanks, I've edited the answer with that in mind.
